# Transaction certificate / TCerts in Hyperledger Fabric 1.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How transaction certificate or TCert is being used in Hyperledger Fabric 1.0? Various documentation said that Tcert is used for each transaction and clients can request for TCert(s). However, I just can't find any more in-depth discussion on this topic in the official documentation. I can't find how it is used even examining the SDK documentation and some samples.

Is it still being used in 1.0+? If yes, where can I find information about how it can be used?

Answer (score 1):

No, TCerts are not supported in Fabric 1.0+

In the future you will be able to use Identity Mixer instead. Check https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2005 for additional info on this work.

Comment: we expect that Identity Mixer will be available as experimental feature in the 1.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

TCerts with IDemixer should give us the ability that the IDEmixer CA of your network issues a IDEmixer certificate only **once* and that can then be used to generate further TCerts.

A few of the features provided should be:

- Unlinkability from IDEMixer Cert ==> TCert
- Public verifyability of a transaction without revealing the ID of the trx issuer
- Selective Deanonymiazation on a per transaction level with selected counter parties